# how do i give commands in python terminal

Tags: python

I have opened anaconda prompt in python terminal using,

```
os.system('cmd /k C:\\Users\\schet\\anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat C:\\Users\\schet\\anaconda3 ')
```

which opens this in the terminal

```
(base) (venv) C:\Users\schet\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv>
```

how do I give command input into the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then now that you can see the Anaconda prompt, you just need to type the word *Python* and you'll be ready to type in and execute Python commands.

Source: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/getting-started/#start-python